# How to identify replacement for power supplies used in small form factor PCs?

Tags: power-supply

I have some small form factor PCs that use power supplies with odd shapes. Since I manage these PCs in bulk (I'm up to about 60 of them), I want to know how to find replacement parts in the inevitable case of a power supply failure. Right now these are fairly new to us, and so I haven't had any failures yet, but I want to be prepared when I do.

There are actually two varieties I am concerned about here, but I also want to know about how to identify these power supplies and valid replacement parts in the more general case.

The two power supplies are as follows:

1. [HP 437352-001](https://www.google.com/search?q=437352-001&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch). It's like a section was removed from a normal supply, but a standard size fan still sits at the back. The power supply here sits over the hard drive, so that fan can cool both parts.
2. The other is a low-power (150W) power supply for a FoxConn-branded machines we have ([example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856119059) of the computer -- couldn't find a good image of the supply itself). It long and skinny, rather than cubish like a typical power supply, and almost looks like a server power supply.

So the question is, how can I find out more about these atypical power supplies? What name (read: google keyword) should I use when talking about them? Where or what kinds of places can I look for replacements?

Comment: I had this problem with my Foxconn motherboard. I found the only way to figure out what fan model it took was to look at the physical sticker on the component.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a little research for you, it looks like the HP 437352-001 power supplies is of form factor [**SFX**](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/power/sup/formSFX-c.html).  I am sure that if you search for that type you can find a supplier.

The tech specs for the [**R30-A1**](http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=Barebone&U=en-us0000090) on FoxConns wesite list the power supply as DSL150P.  It is of type TFX12V.  It can be purchased on any site that sells that type.  I know newegg sells them.

Comment: The item at the SFX link did not match what I'm seeing in my machines, but the TFX type was very helpful.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what I was thinking when I said it was an SFX power supply.  Likely it is just a custom design.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have some sort of identifiable part number, eBay is your friend.

[http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=HP+437352-001&_sacat=0](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=HP%20437352-001&_sacat=0)

Comment: I'm skeptical of getting new replacements this way. I have checked ebay, and mostly what I see are one-offs that likely came from a machine that was used a good deal before something happened to a hard drive or motherboard and the rest was gutted for parts/ebay fodder. Who knows how much life the power supply has left? It's also not fun making purchases from ebay via company purchase order. I'll use ebay if I have to, but it's never going to be my first choice here.

Comment: Can the ebay search give you any useful information to then take to your google search?

Comment: I have tried checking the HP parts store and this is one of those part they consider "non-customer replaceable" so you can't really buy it from them either. I would suggest finding something else that is compatible, but it looks like the p/s has its own unique shape so your options are really limited.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably this outfit, although they don't seem to have that particular model...yet.

http://www.atxpowersupplies.com/hp-power-supplies.php

Oh wait. I see they actually recommend this:
http://www.atxpowersupplies.com/350-watt-cfx-power-supply-SPI350MB-MC.php
(assuming you have HP DC7900 SFF or similar)

This one is the same shape, but some things are rearranged inside. There is a mechanical drawing on the page, with dimensions.